# Unit testing DynamoDB with XUnit and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, moq, xunit

I'm starting to write my DAL for a .Net 6 application that hooks into AWS DynamoDB. We are going for a document model implementation, everything is setup up within AWS already, just need to start the data access with a set of unit and integration tests.

I've tried to start this with my unit tests, in true TDD fashion, but am struggling to mock the DynamoDB client. I haven't found anything that helps with the mocking of DynamoDb but have seen people using DynamoDB locally for this. I don't want to use a local instance for this as it doesn't feel like they are unit tests but also these unit tests will be running as part of the build pipeline within devops so need to run independently.

This gives an idea of what I've been trying to do but I just get an object not set to a reference exception when the client is trying to get the table description and I seem to be going around in circles with this one...can anyone please help?

Code/context below:

```
[Fact]
public void Get_WithValidId_ReturnsEntity()
{
    var mockDynamoClient = new Mock<IAmazonDynamoDB>();
    
    var describeTableResponse = new DescribeTableResponse
    {
        Table = new TableDescription
        {
            TableName = "TestTable"
        },
        HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };

    // Trying a couple of different ways to get the table description
    mockDynamoClient
        .Setup(s => s.DescribeTableAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(describeTableResponse);

    mockDynamoClient
        .Setup(s => s.DescribeTableAsync(It.IsAny<DescribeTableRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
        .ReturnsAsync(describeTableResponse);

    var repo = new DynamoRepository(mockDynamoClient.Object);

    var result = repo.Get(3);

    result.Should().NotBeNull();
}
```

Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Stack Trace

```
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.DescribeTable(String tableName)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Cache`2.GetValueHelper(TKey key, Boolean& isStaleItem, Func`2 creator)
   at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Util.Cache`2.GetValue(TKey key, Func`2 creator, Boolean& isStaleItem)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTableInfo()
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(IAmazonDynamoDB ddbClient, TableConfig config)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(IAmazonDynamoDB ddbClient, String tableName, DynamoDBEntryConversion conversion, Boolean isEmptyStringValueEnabled)
   at Amazon.DynamoDBv2.DocumentModel.Table.LoadTable(IAmazonDynamoDB ddbClient, String tableName)
   at MyApp.Infrastructure.Data.Repositories.DynamoRepository.Get(Int32 id) in C:\projects\MyApp\Infrastructure\Data\Repositories\DynamoRepository.cs:line 29
```

This is the corresponding method (not finished yet) which may give some extra context behind the implementation.

```
public async Task<Document> Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var table = Table.LoadTable(_dynamoDbClient, Constants.DynamoTableName);

        var item = await table.GetItemAsync(id);

        return item;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap Table.LoadTable (and similar methods you use) and extract an interface, inject that into your repo then mock that method call? Else your tests might break everytime the implementation of Table.LoadTable changes and why should you care about DescribeTableAsync etc details?

Let me know if you want me to provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in IAmazonDynamoDB, check this out: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/1589

You need to use a different (request) approach like from AWS examples:

```
public async Task<Document> Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new GetItemRequest
        {
            TableName = Constants.DynamoTableName,
            Key = new Dictionary<string, AttributeValue>
            {
                { "Id", new AttributeValue { N = id.ToString() } }
            }
        };

        var response = await _dynamoDbClient.GetItemAsync(request);

        if (response.Item == null || response.Item.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item not found.");
            return null;
        }

        // Convert the response to a Document (or use the response as is, depending on your needs)
        var document = Document.FromAttributeMap(response.Item);
        return document;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```